# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PERMISSION_DENIED, Access to location data denied, null, null) |Andriod |Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location

I am trying to get the user current location, but when I and click on get location button it gives me this error. I am running this on android.

I have added all dependencies.

Here is my code

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _AppState createState() => _AppState(); 
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  String _locationMessage = ""; 

  void _getCurrentLocation() async {

    final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);

    setState(() {
      _locationMessage = "${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}";
    });

  }


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Location Services")
        ),
        body: Align(
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            Text(_locationMessage), 
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  _getCurrentLocation();
              },
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("Find Location")
            )
          ]),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

i added this on **pubspec.yaml** file

```
  geolocator: ^5.1.5
```

and this on **AndriodManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Please help if anyone know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi There. You need to first request permission to access location. Check out the official doc - https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#example

Comment: Glad to have helped.